# New sentence after semicolon

Tags: punctuation, sentence

After a semicolon what follows isn't capitalized like at the beginning of a sentence. However, what if it were? Would that be incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proper nouns are always capitalized, even if they follow a semicolon; that is true for adjectives derived from proper nouns, when they are normally capitalized.

The "rules" about capitalizing a word after a semicolon are not different from the "rules" about capitalizing a word after a comma.

Comment: yup, a semicolon is basically a special kind of comma.